# GraphStream Edit node attributes and display them in GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, onclicklistener, graphstream

I al using GraphStream to import a file after parsing it and creating nodes with attributes.
What I want after I create the nodes is to edit theirs attribute in the GUI.
Like I have in the right side the Graph and in the left side to appear the properties of the node I click on, in text boxes. Than to save these properties.

My code:

```
frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



        LayersGraph lg=new LayersGraph();
        Viewer viewer=new Viewer ( lg.graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);

        viewer.enableAutoLayout();
        ViewerPipe fromViewer=viewer.newViewerPipe();

        lg.createGraph();



          View view=viewer.addDefaultView(false);


        clisten=new NodeClickListener(fromViewer,view,lg.graph);
        fromViewer.addViewerListener((ViewerListener) clisten);


        frame.getContentPane().add((Component) view);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.WEST);
        textArea.setText("The graph has etc....");
```

The NodeClickListener:

public class NodeClickListener implements ViewerListener , MouseInputListener{

```
public boolean loop = true; 
 private ViewerPipe vpipe = null; 
 private View vw = null; 
 private Graph graph = null; 

 public HashMap<String,String> attributes=new HashMap<String,String>();


 /**
  * Constructor 
  * @param vpipe - Viewer Pipe of the graph UI 
  * @param vw - View of the current graph in swing 
  * @param g - graph object for the current graph in use 
  */ 
 public NodeClickListener(ViewerPipe vpipe, View vw, Graph g) { 
  this.loop=true; 
  this.vpipe = vpipe; 
  this.vw = vw; 
  this.graph = g; 
  // Keep piping back while grph is out to hook mouse clicks 
  this.vw.addMouseListener(this); 

 } 


 /**
  * Close the view when graph is no longer needed and detach all listners 
  * @param id - not used, but inherited by interface 
  */ 
 public void viewClosed(String id) { 
  loop = false; 
  vw.removeMouseListener(this); 


 } 
 /**
  * Button push hook to label nodes/edges 
  * @param id - string id of node 
  */ 
 public void buttonPushed(String id) { 
  System.out.println("Button pushed on node "+id); 
  Node n = graph.getNode(id); 
  //String _ui_label = n.getAttribute("_ui.label"); 
  String ui_label = n.getAttribute("ui.label");  

  System.out.println("ui_label: "+ui_label);


  for(String key:n.getEachAttributeKey()){
      Object value=n.getAttribute(key);
      System.out.println("Key: "+key+" Value: "+value.toString());
      attributes.put(key, value.toString());
  }
  }
```

I want to send the attributes to the form and in form to create dynamically labels and text boxes for each node clicked in order to be able to edit the properties.
Anyone has any idea about how can I do this? It may be also a problem of synchronization between the threads?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me just using JOptionPane dialogs called from the buttonPressed() handler.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    final DefaultGraph g = new DefaultGraph("my beautiful graph");
    g.setStrict(false);
    Viewer viewer = new Viewer(g, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_GUI_THREAD);
    JFrame myJFrame = new JFrame();
    myJFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    DefaultView view = (DefaultView) viewer.addDefaultView(false);   // false indicates "no JFrame".
    view.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    myJFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    myJFrame.add(view);
    JButton myButton = new JButton("MyButton");
    myButton.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Somebody pushed my button."));
    myJFrame.add(myButton);
    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.addChangeListener(e -> view.getCamera().setViewPercent(slider.getValue() / 10.0));
    myJFrame.add(slider);
    myJFrame.pack();
    myJFrame.setVisible(true);
    myJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    viewer.enableAutoLayout();
    ViewerPipe vp = viewer.newViewerPipe();
    vp.addViewerListener(new ViewerListener() {
        @Override
        public void viewClosed(String viewName) {
            // dont care
        }

        @Override
        public void buttonPushed(String id) {
            Node n = g.getNode(id);
            String attributes[] = n.getAttributeKeySet().toArray(new String[n.getAttributeKeySet().size()]);

            String attributeToChange = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Select attibute to modify", "Attribute for " + id, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, attributes, attributes[0]);
            String curValue = n.getAttribute(attributeToChange);
            String newValue
                    = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New Value", curValue);
            n.setAttribute(attributeToChange, newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void buttonReleased(String id) {
            // don't care
        }
    });
    g.addNode("A");
    g.addNode("B");
    g.addNode("C");

    g.addNode("E");
    g.addNode("F");
    g.addNode("G");

    g.addNode("1");
    g.addNode("2");
    g.addNode("3");

    g.addNode("4");
    g.addNode("5");
    g.addNode("6");

    g.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
    g.addEdge("AC", "B", "C");
    g.addEdge("BC", "C", "C");

    g.addEdge("EB", "E", "B");
    g.addEdge("FC", "F", "C");
    g.addEdge("GC", "G", "C");

    g.addEdge("1B", "1", "B");
    g.addEdge("2C", "2", "C");
    g.addEdge("3C", "3", "C");

    g.addEdge("4B", "4", "B");
    g.addEdge("5C", "5", "C");
    g.addEdge("6C", "6", "C");

    g.getNode("A").setAttribute("size", "big");
    g.getNode("B").setAttribute("size", "medium");
    g.getNode("C").setAttribute("size", "small");
    g.getNode("A").setAttribute("ui:color", "red");
    g.getNode("B").setAttribute("ui:color", "blue");
    g.getNode("C").setAttribute("ui:color", "green");

    for (Node node : g) {
        node.addAttribute("ui.label", node.getId());
    }
    while (true) {
        (view).repaint();
        vp.pump();
    }
}
```

Please see [Integrating the viewer in your GUI](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.1/#integrating-the-viewer-in-your-gui)

Should look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Great idea! It works like that, but I want to have the view in a frame in order to add other JButtons for Opening/Saving the graph in a file. But I don't know how to add now other JButtons to the graph. Is it possible to put the graph in a Jframe?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I have I hope the last question :) I don't know why the graph is not displayed totally. I changed the dimension of the view but only 3 nodes are displayed, is like that it is zoomed. If I change the View size or frame dimension I get the same thing. Do you have any idea what it is going wrong?

Comment: I have added 6 more nodes to your example and the graph is not rendered correctly. Which properties should be changed in order to have it all displayed?

Comment: Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287865/graphstream-graph-not-rendered-corectly

Comment: Edited based on work with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287865/graphstream-graph-not-rendered-corectly

Comment: well, i have problems with the graphstream thread and the gui thread but none of the THREADING models worked. When i call the class with the `while(true){viewpipe.pump()}` the view doesnt render the nodes. I saw you using the loop here too, is there any way to not use it?